# How does AWS S3 determine which files need .md5sum files generated for them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, md5sum, data-integrity

I'm uploaded folders with large files to AWS S3.

In the folder, there are many large files. Below are some that AWS generated .md5sums for.

```
A0688.bam   bam 42.8 GB
A0688.bam.md5sum    md5sum  

A0688.vcf.gz    gz  398.9 MB
A0688.vcf.gz.md5sum md5sum  

A0688.hard-filtered.vcf.gz  gz  396.3 MB
A0688.hard-filtered.vcf.gz.md5sum   md5sum  

A0688.cnv.vcf.gz    gz  45.7 KB
A0688.cnv.vcf.gz.md5sum
```

I'm confused why some files, which are as large or larger as some with md5sums, don't seem to get the same treatment.

```
A0688.tn.tsv.gz gz  144.6 MB
A0688.target.counts.gz  gz  105.1 MB

No .md5sums
```

Ideally, I'd like a md5sum for all files... in the event the data needs to be transferred elsewhere, and I can use to do a data integrity check. But struggling to understand how AWS handles these sort of events.

Comment: What tool or library are you using to upload files to S3?  S3 on it's own does not create any such file, nor does it have an option to.

Comment: aws s3 cp. But thank you, this is a great point. Likely my software is creating these values.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken. AWS doesn't create such files, it was my local software automatically producing them.